# Flattening a list of JSON strings with nested dict

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I would like to transform the following `list` of `tuple`s:

```py
[('1599324732926-0',
     {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767,
                "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856,
                "delta":true,
                "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535},
                "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172}
               }'
     }
 )
 ('1599324732926-1',
     {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324832.767,
                "receipt_timestamp":1599324832.9256856,
                "delta":true,
                "bid":{"338.8":0.06482,"338.57":3.95535},
                "ask":{"340.12":2.47578,"340.13":6.43172}
               }'
     }
 )
]
```

Into a `list` of `dict`s or a Dataframe (either one, it is anyway not complicated to go from one to the other):

```
[{
  'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.9,
  'size': 0.06482},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.67,
  'size': 3.95535},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.66,
  'size': 16.78636},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.63,
  'size': 2.5},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.45,
  'size': 6.06071},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.38,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.95,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 338.96,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 339.11,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 339.12,
  'size': 2.47578},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 339.13,
  'size': 6.43172},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 339.36,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 339.52,
  'size': 6.5},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 341.18,
  'size': 0.0},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 341.19,
  'size': 0.0},
  ...
]
```

So basically,

- the first id is dropped (actually, it is kept in a separate list).
- the data in `data` is a JSON object having nested dict.
- the trick is that "bid" and "ask" become values of a key named "side" in the resulting dict.
- keys of the nested dict "bid" and "ask" become values of a key named "price" in the resulting dict.
- values for the price stay values for a key named "size".

I am able to process each JSON element of the list separately.
But lists can have up to 600k elements.
I enquire if it might be possible to process the list as a whole with some pandas or numpy functions to get faster?

I had a look at pandas [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) but according the example given, keys of dict are systematically columns, while in this case, the "price" keys become values of "price" column.

Do you have any idea how I could do that? Is there any way to 1st pre-process the list of JSON so that it can be further processed with `json_normalize()`.

Only for information, here is the code i could write to process each element of the list separately, but I don't think it is the right direction. The next step would be to encapsulate this in a for loop, which will be far slower compare to a solution that manages the list as a whole.

```py
import json

data_light = ('1599324732926-0',
     {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, \
                "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856,\
                "delta":true, \
                "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, \
                "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172} \
               }'
     }
 )

var=json.loads(data_light[1]['data'])
var_bid=var['bid']
var_ask=var['ask']
mylist=list(var_bid.items())+list(var_ask.items())

it = ['ask'] * len(var_ask) + ['bid'] * len(var_bid)

timestamp=var['timestamp']
receipt_timestamp=var['receipt_timestamp']
delta=var['delta']
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[timestamp], [receipt_timestamp], [delta],it], names=['timestamp', 'receipt_timestamp', 'delta', 'side'])

df=pd.DataFrame(mylist, index=midx, columns=['price', 'size'], dtype=float)
my_dict=df.reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's easier to extract the information iteratively, than using `pandas.json_normalize`.
- As the sample data shows, the value of `data` is a `str` type and must be converted to a `dict`.
- The main task is to extract each `key` `value` pair from `'bid'` and `'ask'`, to create a separate record.

  - The list-comprehension performs the task of creating separate records.

```py
import json
import pandas

# list of tuples, where the value of data, is a string
transaction_data = [('1599324732926-0', {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856, "delta":true, "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172}}'}),
                    ('1599324732926-1', {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856, "delta":true, "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172}}'}),
                    ('1599324732926-2', {'data': '{"timestamp":1599324732.767, "receipt_timestamp":1599324732.9256856, "delta":true, "bid":{"338.9":0.06482,"338.67":3.95535}, "ask":{"339.12":2.47578,"339.13":6.43172}}'})]

# create a list of lists for each transaction data
# split each side, key value pair into a separate list
data_key_list = [['timestamp', 'receipt_timestamp', 'delta', 'side', 'price', 'size']]

for v in transaction_data:  # # iterate through each transaction
    data = json.loads(v[1]['data'])  # convert the string to a dict
    for side in ['bid', 'ask']:  # extract each key, value pair as a separate record
        data_key_list += [[data['timestamp'], data['receipt_timestamp'], data['delta'], side, float(k), v] for k, v in data[side].items()]

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_key_list[1:], columns=data_key_list[0])

# display(df.head())
     timestamp  receipt_timestamp  delta side   price     size
0  1.59932e+09        1.59932e+09   True  bid   338.9  0.06482
1  1.59932e+09        1.59932e+09   True  bid  338.67  3.95535
2  1.59932e+09        1.59932e+09   True  ask  339.12  2.47578
3  1.59932e+09        1.59932e+09   True  ask  339.13  6.43172
4  1.59932e+09        1.59932e+09   True  bid   338.9  0.06482
```

## convert to a list of dicts

```py
df.to_dict(orient='records')

[out]:
[{'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 338.9,
  'size': 0.06482},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'bid',
  'price': 338.67,
  'size': 3.95535},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 339.12,
  'size': 2.47578},
 {'timestamp': 1599324732.767,
  'receipt_timestamp': 1599324732.9256856,
  'delta': True,
  'side': 'ask',
  'price': 339.13,
  'size': 6.43172},
 ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly an answer to your question as it is not an implementation of pandas or numpy but I think it should work fine for your need.

Try to take a look at [multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)

Assuming you have a function that receives an tuple from original list and returns the data dictionary that you want. lets say it's signature looks like that:

```
def tuple_to_dict(input):
    # conversion code goes here
    return result_dict
```

You can then use multiprocessing.Pool() like so:

```
import multiprocessing


if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_list = [...] # your input list

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result_list = pool.map(tuple_to_dict, input_list)
        print(result_list)
```

Note:

1. the creation of the Pool() object should be placed inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block or a function that is called from there (recursivley) - otherwise you will get a RuntimeError
2. the `with ... as...`  is placed there so that the Pool object is closed when usage ends or fails. if you do not use the "with / as" syntax use it inside of a try/catch block and add `pool.close()` statment at it's `finally` block to make sure the pool is closed.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the tip. I feel unfortunately my hardware is already at its limit, and I am not sure multiprocessing is actually possible. I am primarily looking for faster code.
Thanks nonetheless! Bests,